# Unable to display HTML Image while using Relative Path when loading with Live Server

Tags: html, css, image, relative-path, src

I am experiencing difficulties when it comes to my jpeg images on Line 14 rendering on the Live Server. I will need to use a Relative Path link, since these images are not on any server.

Ive tried a lot of different path's however sometimes the Alt text appears, and other times, it appears as unreadable text on the Live Server.

I have screenshot attached a picture of my code as well as my folder path on the left side next to the toolbar

Does anyone know what I should insert?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN78o.jpg)

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. Glad to be introduced to such an interactive community.

I tried numerous times to use a Relative Path link however it failed. Used other resources however it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the image from the root directory use this path "./{image_name.jpg}"

If you are trying to get the image from the pics directory use this path "./pics/{image_name.jpg}

for more information consider reading this:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. With your help, I was able to resolve my issue.

For anyone else in this situation that got a image that is not populating, I first recommend opening the image on another window on your web browser of choice, and then saving it locally on your computer. I tried to skip the step of opening the image in a web browser, and it didnt work!